# Make [war-files] a synonym of [.war]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, synonym-request

I found the [.war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.war) and [war-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/war-files) tags. I don't have enough reputation to make tag synonyms, but they seem to be *exactly* the same thing. I propose making [war-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/war-files) a synonym of [.war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.war), because [.war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/.war) has more questions than [war-files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/war-files), so it's probably easier to find.

Comment: [war-files], what is it good for?

Comment: @usr2564301 absolutely nothing

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's make them *both* synonyms of [war](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/war) instead.

Comment: Done, both merged into [war] and synonyms added.

Comment: So what you're saying, Makoto, is that those tags mean war?